# Get elements multiplied by their frequencies from a dictionary

Tags: python, list, dictionary

Suppose there is a dictionary with 1 Million records.

a minimum reproducible example:

```
d = {1:2, 2:4, 3:5}
```

here keys represent the elements and values represent their respective frequencies.

Now, I want to get all the elements in a list like:

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

I did this:

```
lst=[]
for key, freq in d.items():
  for _ in range(freq):
    lst.append(key)

print(lst)
#[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

The problem is that this method is slow `O(N**2)`.

I can do the same thing in list comprehension but, still it will have 2 nested loops.

What could be an elegant solution to this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With combination of [itertools](https://docs.python.org/3/library/itertools.html)`.[chain, starmap, repeat]`:

```
from itertools import chain, starmap, repeat

d = {1:2, 2:4, 3:5}
lst = list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, d.items())))
print(lst)
```

---

```
[1, 1, 2, 2, 2, 2, 3, 3, 3, 3, 3]
```

---

Another alternative using list comprehension:

```
lst = [i for k,v in d.items() for i in [k]*v]
```

---

Timings on a bit extended dict `d = {1:2, 2:4, 3:5, 4:6, 5:7, 7:10, 8:8, 9:10, 10:15}`:

```
In [341]: %timeit list(Counter(d).elements())
2.51 µs ± 48.3 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 100,000 loops each)

In [342]: %timeit [i for k,v in d.items() for i in [k]*v]
1.92 µs ± 25.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)

In [343]: %timeit list(chain.from_iterable(starmap(repeat, d.items())))
1.51 µs ± 18.2 ns per loop (mean ± std. dev. of 7 runs, 1,000,000 loops each)
```

Comment: Thanks Roman +1.. I am waiting for more responses if any.

Comment: What's the complexity here?

Comment: @Goku, you're welcome

Comment: @Sebastian neither this solution nor Goku's solution have or can have asymptotically better time complexity than the solution presented in the question. Goku's time complexity analysis is wrong, none of the solutions is or can be O(n²). See my answer.

Comment: Hacky short version: `lst = [*Counter.elements(d)]` ([that function](https://github.com/python/cpython/blob/cb1f49991e86d773f6d36a49b81be12abf811057/Lib/collections/__init__.py#L626-L644) doesn't mind getting an ordinary dict instead of a Counter).

Answer (score 4):

This

```py
lst=[]
for key, freq in d.items():
  for _ in range(freq):
    lst.append(key)
```

is asymptotically optimal: `lst` needs to have exactly sum over counts elements. There is no way to go below this. You spend amortized constant time on each element (`append` is an amortized constant time operation).

This is **not** O(n²). Time complexity is not as simple as "number of nested loops = power of n". What would n even be here? It can't be number of items in the dict - if I give you `{1: k}`, that will take O(k) to run despite n being fixed at one. Always consider until where your loops go - one of your loops runs n times, but how often the inner loop runs is independent of n.

Instead, this is O(sum over counts), which, as said, is asymptotically optimal (though still pretty bad (exponential) in terms of the input size). Do you really want to repeat each key `value` times?

That doesn't mean that it's practically optimal - the constant factors can be reduced, as Roman has demonstrated. For example you could also count how long the list will need to be by summing over the values, then creating a list with the proper capacity such that no reallocations will be needed.

Either way, neither your second proposed solution nor Roman's proposed solution are asymptotically faster than your current solution.

Comment: Thanks luatic for your explanation..+1 much appreciated